# How to bind and create html coming from asp.net web api with client side <ul> element?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, content-negotiation

I want to return html output from api. The output is in form of a list. I want to fetch this html list from api and bind it to the  element on my client side.

The api looks like:

```
public IHttpActionResult LoadCities()
            {
                    IList<CityEntity> cityList = new List<CityEntity>();
                    _popularDetails = _container.Resolve<IPopularDetails>();
                    cityList = _popularDetails.GetUsedCarCities();
                    return Ok(cityList);                
            }
```

The single entity looks like: (We have 200 objects returning like this)

```
 public class CityEntity
    {
        public int CityId { get; set; }    
        public string CityName { get; set; }
    }
```

This is ajax call that has return datatype html

```
 $.ajax({
                  type: 'GET',
                  url: '/webapi/namespace/LoadCities/?',
                  dataType: 'html',
                  context: this,
                  success: function (htmlResult) {

                        }
        });
```

The html returned is also not looking like html :)

It looks like- [{"cityId":196,"cityName":"A&N Islands"},{"cityId":333,"cityName":"Abohar"}....

Although i want this to be like:
AN Islands

How can i do this, where should i append these li tags and what should i do to attach these li to the main ul element?

Comment: webapi doesn't return html it returns xml or json.  what you are sending back is json.

Answer (score 1):

There's a couple things going on here.  First I would re-write you controller to take your external dependencies in as a constructor parameter.  Then I would re-write you method

```
public IHttpActionResult LoadCities()
{
    return Ok(_popularDetails.GetUsedCarCities());                
}
```

because _popularDetails is now being passed in through the contructor.

Your jQuery call can then be

```
 $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: '/webapi/namespace/LoadCities',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: 'json'
 }).done(function(data) {
         var html = '<ul>';

    jQuery.each(data, function (index, item) {
        html += "<li>item.cityId + " " + item.cityName</li>";

        html += '</ul>';

      $(<some-element-selector>").html(html);
  });
```

you may have to change the jquery a little.  Debug into done promise and see the structure that it sent back.

Comment: Since the list i have is too long. Can we create the complete html on server side only. This i think would save the client side computations.

Comment: What is your front end?  An aspt.net mvc application?  you could always make a call from mvc to the webapi and generate your html there.  your question doesn't mention any ui other than the jquery call.